# How to use the null-conditional operator on an empty list?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have an object (keeping it simple for this example), such as:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public ICollection<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
}

public class OtherObject
{
    public bool IsValid() { return true; }
}
```

Currently in my code I do:

```
bool ok = false;
if (myObject.OtherObjects != null && myObject.OtherObjects.Count > 0)
{
    var last = myObject.OtherObjects.Last();
    ok = last.IsValid();
}
```

Now, with C#6.0, it would have been possible to do this in one line of code as:

```
bool? ok = myObject.OtherObjects?.Last()?.IsValid();
```

However, in this situation, the null-conditional operator won't work because the above returns an exception

> The sequence contains no elements.

So in these kinds of situations, do I still need to use the old method of checking for nulls instead of the new method using the null-conditional operator?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: `.LastOrDefault()`. Obviously, there is no *general* way to reduce any operation on an empty list to a no-op (unless you write some needlessly funky extension method); lists are not so primitive a concept in C#.

Comment: The list contains no elements, but it is *not* null otherwise you'd get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: How about `var last = myObject?.OtherObjects?.LastOrDefault(); bool ok = last?.IsValid() ?? false;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The null conditional operator combines nicely with `LastOrDefault()` as @Jeroen mentioned.

You can simply do:

```
bool ok = myObject.OtherObjects?.LastOrDefault()?.IsValid() ?? false;
```

Answer (score 1):

The list contains no elements, but it is not `null` otherwise you'd get a `NullReferenceException`. What you can do is change it to something like that :

```
bool? ok = myObject.OtherObjects?.Any() ?? false && myObject.OtherObjects.Last().IsValid();
```